# Structure of multiple nested Mongoose promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, response

How would I structure a function that has multiple `Mongoose.findOne()` nested in each other?

I need to do something like

```
const userId  = '...';
const postId  = '...';
const imageId = '...';

User.findById(userId).then(user => {
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      status: 'error',
      err: 'User not found',
    });
  }

  Post.findById(postId).then(post => {
    if (!post) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        status: 'error',
        err: 'Post not found',
      });
    }

    Image.findById(imageId).then(image => {
      if (!image) {
        return res.status(400).json({
        status: 'error',
        err: 'Image not found',
      });

      // DO SOMETHING WITH VARIABLES 'user', 'post', AND 'image'

    }).catch(err => { .. });
  }).catch(err => { .. });
}).catch(err => { .. });
```

Since `Collection.findById()` returns a promise, I guess I should use chaining instead of this structure.

So it might be something like

```
User
  .findById(userId)
  .then(user => Post.findById(postId))
  .then(post => Image.findById(imageId))
  .then(image => {
      // DO SOMETHING WITH VARIABLES 'user', 'post', AND 'image'
  });
  .catch(err => { .. });
```

but I don't know how to access the variables `user`, `post`, and `image`, and how to throw the errors, so I can access them in my `catch` statement.

## Edit

I have tried this

```
async function getPostAsync() {
  const userId = '597989c668189f31483ffdbf';
  const postId = '597989c62624ea74750c74f8';

  if (!userId) {
    throw new Error('User id missing');
  }

  if (!postId) {
    throw new Error('Post id missing');
  }

  const user = await User.findById(userId);
  const post = await Post.findById(postId);

  return post;
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  getPostAsync().then(post => {
    res.json({
      status: 'success',
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: 'error',
      err
    });
  })
});
```

but I just receive

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "err": {}
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

But I get the same result even with

```
async function getPostAsync() {
  throw new Error('msg');
  return Post.find();
}
```

so I might be calling the async function wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access those variables inside a later promise's `then`, but you can get round it by assigning the local resolved values to global variables

```
let globalUser, globalPost; // create variables for later

User
    .findById(userId)
    .then(user => {
        globalUser = user; // assign to global
        return Post.findById(postId)
    })
    .then(post => {
        globalPost = post; // assign to global
        return Image.findById(imageId)
    })
    .then(image => {
        // DO SOMETHING WITH VARIABLES 'globalUser', 'globalPost', AND 'image'
    })
    .catch(err => {... });
```

**EDIT**: or when using [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
async function() {
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    const post = await Post.findById(postId);
    const image = await Image.findById(imageId);

    // do something with user, post and image
}
```

Seeing as your promises don't rely on each other you could also use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in an async function:

```
async function() {
    const result = await Promise.all([
        User.findById(userId),
        Post.findById(postId),
        Image.findById(imageId)
    ]);

    const [user, post, image] = result;

    // do something with user, post and image
}
```

**EDIT 2**: Error handling

```
async function getImage() {
    let user;
    try {
        user = await User.findById(userId);
    } catch (error) { // deal with rejection of `User.findById`
        // do something with error
    }

    // if these fail the entire function will throw
    const post = await Post.findById(postId);
    const image = await Image.findById(imageId);

    return image;
}

getImage()
    .then(image => {... })
    .catch(error => {... }); // deal with rejection of `getImage` as a whole
```

The above code showcases the ways you can handle errors in an async function. The first is how we deal with an error in the `User.findById` function, by simply wrapping it in a `try catch` block.

The second method is by simply letting the entire async function throw an error. I.e. if the `Post.findById` or `Image.findById` promises reject, the entire `getImage()` promise will reject, which you can deal with in the `.catch()` handler.

Comment: What if I use a completely different structure with `async` and `await`?

Comment: Thanks!! But I only want to look for post if the user was found. Will this approach abort the `Post.findById()` and `Image.findById()` if post wasn't found? Or do I have to use `if (!!userId) { const post = await Post.findById(postId); if (!!post) { const image = await Image.findById(imageId); ... } }`?

Comment: It's not clear from your code which queries depend on each other, but if one does depend on another then yes you could separate the queries and only trigger the next query if the earlier one was successful. You could also just let the promise fail naturally if one of the variables (e.g. `postId`) is not defined.

Comment: Okay thanks. Regarding your async function, where do you catch errors? I assume I should use `async function getPostsAsync() { ... }` and use it with `getPostsAsync().then(result => {}).catch(err => {})`, but I don't know how to throw the errors for every Mongoose call (and normal error checking) in the async function

Comment: But I mean if I have to throw an error if a normal if statement fails, such as `if (!post) { .. }` (i.e. if promise was successful, but the post was null/not found) or just `if (false) { .. }`. Would it also just be `if (x) { throw 'error' }`?

Comment: Then just do `if (!post) throw new Error('didnt find post')`

Comment: I'm sorry for being annoying, but I'm just not able to get the right result :( I have updated my question

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure why you're getting that particular error. It might be worth creating a new question for it, as these comments are getting crowded.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
Promise.all([
    User.findById(userId),
    Post.findById(postId),
    Image.findById(imageId)
])
.then(result)=>{
    let user = result[0];
    let post = result[1];
    let image = result[2];
})
.catch(err => { .. });
```

Or with [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
Promise.all([
    User.findById(userId),
    Post.findById(postId),
    Image.findById(imageId)
])
.then(([user, post, image])=>{...})
.catch(err => { .. });
```